# search for an image on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

hello im working on implementing azubu.tv livestreams on my website.

Since the page doesnt offer an API and embed code yet i have to improvisize a bit ^^

I just found out that a stream which is live has a special image on the site, namely:
http://www.azubu.tv/static/images/channels/live_check.png

So for example lets take this stream
http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2125982481001

if the guy is livestreaming, the image is there, if hes not, the image is not on the page. I guess if i could some kind of search for the image on the page, i could find out if hes online or not.

Anyone has an idea how to code this

Edit: my exact problem is that i dont know if something like this is possible. So with this thread i want to know if it is possible, and how.

Edit2:

I tried it this way, but still doesnt work sadly:
load('http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2220181926001 .img');

I figured this could work, since its the only img on the page without id afaik.

Comment: This question is too broad. I would suggest doing some work, narrowing your issue down to a problem, and presenting your code. Otherwise we will not be able to help you : )

Comment: My problem is, that i dont even know how to try it

Comment: Have they got some kind of developer API you can use to reliably retrieve this information, that way at least it's safer than trying to find an image on page, and will probably be faster...

Comment: sadly they dont have one yet, since the page is pretty new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question, it's possible to check if the image is present using jQuery selector. Try this:

```
if ($( "[src|='http://www.azubu.tv/static/images/channels/live_check.png']" ).length > 0) {
    alert('Is live');
}
else {
    alert('Not live');
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAFm5/). But you can't trust on an image to check if is live or not (The src of the image can change).

**EDIT**
After reading your comment on my previous answer, I think of one way of working around the problem would be this:

First, you need to load the page you want to check using `jQuery load` and then check if the image is present in the content load.

Let's assumme you have a div with id `container`. You could do something like this:

```
$( "#container" ).load(
    "/echo/html/",     // using jsFiddle echo service to return the 
                       // html below (docs: 
                       // http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)
    {
        html: "<img src='http://www.azubu.tv/static/images/channels/live_check.png' />" +
              "<div id='div_2'>Div 2</div>" +
              "<div id='div_3'>Div 3</div>"
    },
    function( responseText, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest ){
        if ( textStatus == "success" ) {
if ($( "[src|='http://www.azubu.tv/static/images/channels/live_check.png']" ).length > 0) {
    alert('Is live');
}
else {
    alert('Not live');
}
        }
    }
);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fTTV/1/)

Hope it helps!

Note. Due proxy restrictions I can't test your URL. :S

Comment: Thanks for the help, but sadly this does not solve my problem.
Because the image exists all the time. And i wanna check if the img is on a certain page for example: http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2125982481001

Comment: hmm thx again, but im kind of failing. I have never used JQuery before, (i know, what a shame :P ) and I dont even get my code running like it does in your fiddle.
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:30ac
Can you explain me what i do wrong? If i open this file in my localhost its just blank, it wont load the img into the container. I already checked that Jquery is working.

Comment: My code won't work out of jsfiddle. It's a sample of how to do it. To make it work in your code, try this between your `script tags` `$( "#container" ).load('http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2125982481001', function( responseText, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest ){ if ( textStatus == "success" ) { if ($( "[src|='http://www.azubu.tv/static/images/channels/live_check.png']" ).length > 0) {alert('Is live');}else {alert('Not live');}}});`

Comment: hm my problem is that the load function seems to not work. No matter if i want to load the full page, or only the image as you do in the fiddle. It wont load into the div, and neither show if I check in my localhost. Any ideas?